# Python : concatenating dev/random output to a string

Tags: python, random, unicode

I want to concatenate the output bytes from /dev/random to a string that I am generating in my program. But this is giving me errors :

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So i converted the dev/random output to unicode

```
unicode(s, errors='ignore')
```

But this again fails if the output from /dev/random happens to a large number (long) since that wont match to a unicode value. As of now i am reading 42 bytes from dev/random using

```
open("/dev/random","rb").read(42)
```

But this can be any number of bytes. What is a safe way to concatenate these values so that the program does not fail for any values.

Comment: How big a number are we talking? For very large numbers bar talking an age to generate will cause a MemoryError. You might also find /dev/urandom is more suitable and faster unless we are talking cryptography, also where are you running this from?

Comment: You have not posted the code which raises that error. You should post a small but complete program which shows your problem. Otherwise we can only take guesses.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a much easier way than accessing "/dev/random" directly

```
>>> import os
>>> os.urandom(42)
b'\xb1\xc5"_>\x18\xdc\xb7\x0f\xc0\x86\x15\x00&\xc2S\x94\xf3\x10eT\xc5<\xbf3\x99\xd6\xa8\x06\xa3\x8fh@E7\xde8&k\xcd9\xcd'
```

If you really need to use /dev/random (which can block), have a look in `os.py` and you will find this:

```
if not _exists("urandom"):
    def urandom(n):
        """urandom(n) -> str

        Return a string of n random bytes suitable for cryptographic use.

        """
        try:
            _urandomfd = open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)
        except (OSError, IOError):
            raise NotImplementedError("/dev/urandom (or equivalent) not found")
        try:
            bs = b""
            while n - len(bs) >= 1:
                bs += read(_urandomfd, n - len(bs))
        finally:
            close(_urandomfd)
        return bs
```

Note that because this is in `os.py` -  `open`, `read`, `close` and `O_RDONLY` are `os.open`, `os.read`, `os.close` and `os.O_RDONLY` respectively.

If you substitute "urandom" -> "random", you'll get something that works using "/dev/random" - and blocks whenever /dev/random is exausted.

Comment: This actually access `/dev/urandom` which is different from `/dev/random`

Comment: OPs question is how to convert arbitrary bytes to Unicode, not how to get 42 random bytes.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I agree that unless you know what you are doing you should use `os.urandom()` and/or `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/random` but it is irrelevant for the error in the question (*"'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 "*) that corresponds to the title. `u"abc" + os.urandom(42)` may raise the same error.

Comment: _decoding_ a _random_ collection of bytes to a unicode object makes no sense. So the real question is _why_ does the OP _think_ they need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a random bytestring to Unicode, you could use `'latin-1'` encoding that translates `n`-th byte to `n`-th Unicode codepoint:

```
>>> bytearray(range(0x100)).decode('latin-1')
'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\...'
```